# jquery next() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive made a fiddle of my problem here.

http://jsfiddle.net/E9cUS/1/

JavaScript:

```
$('.top').click(function () {
    var thisPage = $(this).closest('.yesNoItem');
    $('.yesNoTick').stop().animate({"opacity" : 1},400, function () {
        thisPage.find('.no .top').stop().animate({"opacity" : 0},400, function () {
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
    });
});

$('.yesNoNext').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.yesNoItem').stop().animate({"opacity" : 0},400, function () {
        //This isnt working? Please advise?
        $(this).next('.yesNoItem').stop().animate({"opacity" : 1},400);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="stage">
    <div class="yesNoOuter">

        <div class="yesNoItem" style="opacity:1;">
            <div class="yesNoContainer yes">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="yesNoTick"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="yesNoContainer no">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="yesNoTick"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>Text 1</p>
                    <div class="yesNoNext">More</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="yesNoItem">
            <div class="yesNoContainer yes">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="yesNoTick"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="yesNoContainer no">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="yesNoTick"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>Text 2</p>
                    <div class="yesNoNext">More</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

I've also put the line of code thats not working.

Bascially it is hiding the element that I want, but not fading the next one in...

Can any one advise based upon my code? Many thanks!

Comment: I think your HTML got messed up. The second `.yesNoItem` element is not a sibling but a **child** of the first `.yesNoItem` element (right click -> inspect element). Probably because of `<div class="yesNoNext">More</span>` (opening `div`, closing `span`). If you correct your HTML it should work (at least it should select the right element). If they are actually supposed to be nested, then `.next()` is the wrong method anyways. Learn about the developer tools, they are invaluable for debugging.

Comment: Most browsers have a "developer tools" functionality that includes a JavaScript console. Have you checked yours to see if there are any errors?

Comment: could you perhaps modify your HTML so that we can see exactly what the heck it is we're supposed to press?

Comment: Wednesday blues. Thanks Felix, such a simple fix that I overlooked. Many thanks

Comment: @FelixKling, Your comment deserves to be an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your HTML got messed up. The second `.yesNoItem` element is not a sibling but a **child** of the first `.yesNoItem` element (right click -> inspect element).

Probably because of `<div class="yesNoNext">More</span>` (opening `div`, closing `span`). The browser will attempt to correct this automatically and just ignore the closing `span` tag (at least this seems to be the case if you inspect the DOM).

If you correct your HTML it should work (at least it should select the right element).

If they are actually supposed to be nested, then `.next()` is the wrong method anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You had an error in your markup

```
<div class="yesNoNext">More</span>
```

if you correct that, next() works http://jsfiddle.net/E9cUS/2/

Comment: Ill wait to see if Felix posts a response, as he answered the question first of all, if not I will accept :)

Comment: @GraemeLeighfield  i didn't see his answer, i was checking your code on jsfiddle, in any case if he solved thi before me he should get credit! :)